# when i running the below code iam getting handle is invalid it takes a string and pass it to remote batch file

Tags: c#, process, scripting

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security;
namespace SampleProject
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            String input = textBox1.Text;

            try
            {

                Process ps = new Process();

                ps.StartInfo.FileName = @"\\199.63.55.163\d$\hello.bat";

                ps.StartInfo.Arguments = input;

                ps.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

                String domain = ps.StartInfo.Domain;

                ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

                ps.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                ps.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"d:\praveen";

                ps.StartInfo.UserName = "Raj";

                ps.StartInfo.Domain = "domain";

                ps.StartInfo.Password = Encrypt("Hello123");


                ps.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                ps.Start();

                ps.WaitForExit();

                MessageBox.Show(ps.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public static SecureString Encrypt(String pwd)
        {
            SecureString ss = new SecureString();

            for (int i = 0; i < pwd.Length; i++)
            {
                ss.AppendChar(pwd[i]);


            }

            return ss;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line of that causes the error?

Comment: Sorry (offtopic) but SecureString? Can't you make the contructor accept a string and only have to do a 'return new SecureString(pwd)'

Answer (score 0):

It's a shot in the dark, but I think that you can't read the processes standard output once it has exited.

Also you have to redirect it - take a look at this documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [.NET Process Start Process Error using credentials (The handle is invalid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628191/net-process-start-process-error-using-credentials-the-handle-is-invalid) ? You need to assign RedirectStandardInput, RedirectStandardOutput, RedirectStandardError